# estructurar contenido

Tags: angularjs

Buenas tardes,

me encuentro realizando un proyecto usando angular 1.5.8 y tengo un par de dudas que no se como estructurarlo correctamente, vamos al tema, tengo un controlador para añadir un objeto a mi proyecto, dentro de este controlador tengo 2 mas, uno se encarga de subir una imagen pequeña que seria referenciada al index del proyecto, y el otro tiene la subida de 3 imágenes mas que serian vistas al "entrar" a la pagina del objeto, el caso es que cuando guardo el objeto y creo el objeto de 0 no puedo cambiar los valores de los objetos que están dentro de este controlador, así que la idea seria pasar los objetos de estos 2 controladores a una factoría y hacer todo con esta. Aqui vienen las preguntas:

¿Seria la mejor opción pasar estos objetos a la factoría y trabajar con ella o pasarlo a $rootScope?
¿Si quito estos 2 controladores, lo tendría todo en el mismo controler y no tendría este problema ya que veria todo desde el controlador, seria así lo mas correcto?
Alguna sugerencia de como estructurarlo y ordenarlo.

controlador principal:

```
app.controller('addVehicleConcesionario', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
      $scope.newCarConcesionario = {
            matricula: '',
            miniatura: '',
            foto1: '',
            foto2: '',
            foto3: ''
        };
        $scope.matvalida = false;
        $scope.matocupada = false;
        $scope.successSaveNewCarCon = false;

        $scope.insertVehiculoConcesionario = function () {
            $scope.newCarConcesionario.miniatura = $scope.miniaturaConcesionario;
            $scope.newCarConcesionario.foto1 = $scope.Foto1.imageConcesionario;
            $scope.newCarConcesionario.foto2 = $scope.Foto2.imageConcesionario;
            $scope.newCarConcesionario.foto3 = $scope.Foto3.imageConcesionario;
            $http({
                url: 'http://localhost/php/newVehicleConcesionario.php',
                data: $scope.newCarConcesionario,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                method: 'POST'
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.save) {
                    $scope.successSaveNewCarCon = true;
                    $scope.newCarConcesionario = {
                        matricula: '',
                        miniatura: '',
                        foto1: '',
                        foto2: '',
                        foto3: ''                  
                    };
                    $timeout(function(){
                        $scope.successSaveNewCarCon = false;
                    },3000);
                    $scope.miniaturaConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
                    $scope.Foto1.imageConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
                    $scope.Foto2.imageConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
                    $scope.Foto3.imageConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
                    $scope.matvalida = false;
                }
            }, function (response) {
                console.log('error' + response);
            });
        };

        $scope.checkMatricula = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/php/concesionarioFunctions.php',
                params: {id: 5, mat: $scope.newCarConcesionario.matricula}
            }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.libre) {
                    $scope.matocupada = false;
                    $scope.matvalida = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.matocupada = true;
                    $scope.matvalida = false;
                }
            }, function (data) {
                console.log('hr' + data.data);
            });
        }
    });
```

este controlador estaría dentro del controlador primero, gestiona la subida de imágenes

```
app.controller('photoController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.imageConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
    $scope.uploadComplete = {uno: false, dos: false, tres: false};
    $scope.$parent.uploadComplete = {uno: false, dos: false, tres: false};
    $scope.Foto1 = {progress: 0, imageConcesionario: 'to_upload.png'};
    $scope.Foto2 = {progress: 0, imageConcesionario: 'to_upload.png'};
    $scope.Foto3 = {progress: 0, imageConcesionario: 'to_upload.png'};
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (id, file, errFiles) {
        switch (id) {
            case 1:
                $scope.Foto1.file = file;
                break;
            case 2:
                $scope.Foto2.file = file;
                break;
            case 3:
                $scope.Foto3.file = file;
                break;
        }
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost/php/uploadPhoto.php',
                data: {file: file, tipo: 4},
                method: 'POST',
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    switch (id) {
                        case 1:
                            $scope.uploadComplete.uno = true;
                            $scope.Foto1 = {file: '', imageConcesionario: response.data.name};
                            $scope.$parent.Foto1 = $scope.Foto1;
                            $scope.$parent.uploadComplete.uno = true;

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            $scope.uploadComplete.dos = true;
                            $scope.Foto2 = {file: '', imageConcesionario:     response.data.name};
                            $scope.$parent.Foto2 = $scope.Foto2;
                            $scope.$parent.uploadComplete.dos = true;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            $scope.uploadComplete.tres = true;
                            $scope.Foto3 = {file: '', imageConcesionario: response.data.name};
                            $scope.$parent.Foto3 = $scope.Foto3;
                            $scope.$parent.uploadComplete.tres = true;
                            break;
                    }
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                    evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    } }]);
```

este ultimo estaría junto al anterior dentro del principal, pero se encargaria de la subida de imágenes miniatura para el index

```
app.controller('miniaturaController', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout','$http', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout, $http) {
    $scope.miniaturaConcesionario = 'to_upload.png';
    $scope.uploadCompleteMiniature = false;
    $scope.$parent.uploadCompleteMiniature = $scope.uploadCompleteMiniature;
    $scope.uploadFiles = function (file, errFiles) {
        $scope.f = file;
        $scope.errFile = errFiles && errFiles[0];
        if (file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'http://localhost/php/uploadPhotoMini.php',
                data: {file: file, tipo: 0},
                method: 'POST',
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                    $scope.miniaturaConcesionario = response.data.name;
                    $scope.$parent.miniaturaConcesionario = response.data.name;
                    $scope.f = '';
                    $scope.uploadCompleteMiniature = true;
                    $scope.$parent.uploadCompleteMiniature = $scope.uploadCompleteMiniature;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 *
                    evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

aquí esta el html:

```
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" ng-controller="addVehicleConcesionario">
        <div class="text-center center-block">
            <form name="newVehicleCon" novalidate class="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Insertar Vehiculo en el Concesionario</legend>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Matricula</span>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Matricula" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" class="form-control" ng-change="checkMatricula()"
                               name="matriculaCon" required
                               ng-model="newCarConcesionario.matricula"/>
                        <span ng-show="matvalida" class="input-group-addon" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="Matricula libre"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </span>
                        <span ng-show="matocupada" class="input-group-addon" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="Matricula ocupada"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-left" ng-show="newVehicleCon.matriculaCon.$invalid">
                        Campo Requerido
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-show="newVehicleCon.descripcionCon.$invalid">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="http://concesionario.antonioextremera.com/img/ventaVehiculos/miniatura/{{miniaturaConcesionario}}"
                                 ng-show="miniaturaConcesionario.length>0"
                                 class="img-responsive" ng-bind="miniaturaConcesionario"/>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Miniatura</h3>

                                <div ng-show="!uploadCompleteMiniature">
                                    Sin imagen.
                                </div>
                                <br/>

                                <p>
                                    <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
                                            accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="150" ngf-max-width="320"
                                            ngf-max-size="3MB">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <br><br>
                                    File:
                                <div style="font:smaller">{{miniatura.file.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}}
                                    {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                                    <div class="progress" ng-show="miniatura.file.progress >= 0">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{miniatura.file.progress}}"
                                             aria-valuemin="0"
                                             aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{miniatura.file.progress}}%;"
                                             ng-bind="miniatura.file.progress + '%'">
                                            {{miniatura.file.progress}}%
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{errorMsg}}
                                <div ng-show="uploadCompleteMiniature">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button"
                                            ng-click="deleteImageConcesionario(0,0,miniaturaConcesionario)"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <div ng-controller="photoController">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="http://concesionario.antonioextremera.com/img/ventaVehiculos/{{Foto1.imageConcesionario}}"
                                 ng-show="imageConcesionario.length>0"
                                 class="img-responsive"/>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Foto 1</h3>

                                <div ng-show="!uploadComplete.uno">
                                    Sin imagen.
                                </div>
                                <br/>

                                <p>
                                    <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles(1,$file, $invalidFiles)"
                                            accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="720" ngf-max-width="1280"
                                            ngf-max-size="3MB">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <br><br>
                                    File:
                                <div style="font:smaller">{{Foto1.file.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}}
                                    {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                                    <div class="progress" ng-show="Foto1.file.progress >= 0">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
                                             aria-valuenow="{{Foto1.file.progress}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                                             aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Foto1.file.progress}}%;"
                                             ng-bind="Foto1.file.progress + '%'">
                                            {{Foto1.file.progress}}%
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{errorMsg}}
                                <div ng-show="uploadComplete.uno">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button" ng-click="deleteImageConcesionario(1,1,Foto1.imageConcesionario)"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="http://concesionario.antonioextremera.com/img/ventaVehiculos/{{Foto2.imageConcesionario}}"
                                 ng-show="imageConcesionario.length>0"
                                 class="img-responsive"/>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Foto 2</h3>

                                <div ng-show="!uploadComplete.dos">
                                    Sin imagen.
                                </div>
                                <br/>

                                <p>
                                    <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles(2,$file, $invalidFiles)"
                                            accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="720" ngf-max-width="1280"
                                            ngf-max-size="3MB">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <br><br>
                                    File:
                                <div style="font:smaller">{{Foto2.file.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}}
                                    {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                                    <div class="progress" ng-show="Foto2.file.progress >= 0">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
                                             aria-valuenow="{{Foto2.file.progress}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                                             aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Foto2.file.progress}}%;"
                                             ng-bind="Foto2.file.progress + '%'">
                                            {{Foto2.file.progress}}%
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{errorMsg}}
                                <div ng-show="uploadComplete.dos">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button" ng-click="deleteImageConcesionario(2,1,Foto2.imageConcesionario)"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img ng-src="http://concesionario.antonioextremera.com/img/ventaVehiculos/{{Foto3.imageConcesionario}}"
                                 ng-show="imageConcesionario.length>0"
                                 class="img-responsive"/>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Foto 3</h3>

                                <div ng-show="!uploadComplete.tres">
                                    Sin imagen.
                                </div>
                                <br/>

                                <p>
                                    <button type="file" ngf-select="uploadFiles(3,$file, $invalidFiles)"
                                            accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="720" ngf-max-width="1280"
                                            ngf-max-size="3MB">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <br><br>
                                    File:
                                <div style="font:smaller">{{Foto3.file.name}} {{errFile.name}} {{errFile.$error}}
                                    {{errFile.$errorParam}}
                                    <div class="progress" ng-show="Foto3.file.progress >= 0">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
                                             aria-valuenow="{{Foto3.file.progress}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                                             aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{Foto3.file.progress}}%;"
                                             ng-bind="Foto3.file.progress + '%'">
                                            {{Foto3.file.progress}}%
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {{errorMsg}}
                                <div ng-show="uploadComplete.tres">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" role="button" ng-click="deleteImageConcesionario(3,1,Foto3.imageConcesionario)"><span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div ng-show="matocupada" class="alert alert-danger">
                    La matricula <b>{{newCarConcesionario.matricula}}</b> esta ocupada, revise el campo.
                </div>
                <button type="button" ng-click="insertVehiculoConcesionario()" class="brn btn-primary form-control" ng-disabled="!newVehicleCon.$valid || !matvalida || !uploadComplete.uno || !uploadComplete.dos || !uploadComplete.tres || !uploadCompleteMiniature"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Insertar Vehiculo
                </button>
                <br/>
                <div ng-show="successSaveNewCarCon" class="alert alert-success">
                    Veh&iacute;culo guardado correctamente.
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Muchas gracias,

un saludo.

Comment: Hola @Antonio. Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías publicar el código mostrando dónde está fallando? Por favor agrega un [mcve]. Además, quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: @Mariano buenas, ya he añadido el código que estoy usando para que se tenga una mejor idea, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mejor en este caso es crear un servicio, cada vez que necesites hacer un request hacia una API, es bueno crear una factoría o un servicio, por ejemplo, intenta enviar los métodos `insertVehiculoConcesionario` y `checkMatricula` a un servicio y luego llámalos desde el controlador correspondiente.

Aquí te envío un link que contiene una guía para crear aplicaciones en Angular 1: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#startup-logic

Comment: Buenas noches, al final elimine los 2 controladores de las fotos y adapte la subida de imágenes para que trabaje con las fotos del vehículo en cuestión y la miniatura, pase las propiedades de estos controladores al principal. Cambiare funciones pasandolas a factoria. Mirare el link que me acabas de pasar, gracias. Un saludo.